# Extract the bit stream (0 and 1) of an object

Tags: c++, object

I need to get the bits of an object. In other words I want to treat an object as a raw data and extract the 0 and 1 bits of it. How can I do this?

For example I have a vector of a user-defined type called **vec** as following,

```
std::vector<NodeEntry *> vec;
```

**vec** points to an object. This object is in memory and consists of 0 and 1 bits. How can I extract the bit stream (0 and 1) of this object.

Comment: You want to get the bits of a an array of pointers ?
What good will that do ?

Comment: I want to get the bits of the object that the vec variable is refering to. I want to apply an erasure code algorithm on the bits. In other words the input of the erasure code algorithm is raw data (0 and 1 bits).

Comment: Cast the pointer to char* or byte* or whatever and have at it.  Of course, figuring out the size of the object can be a challenge.

Comment: And if you're planning to modify the object you'd better be sure to somehow avoid stomping on any system-critical info.

Comment: you could get the address of the object read in the data at the address (for the size of the object) as a `byte*` and then work with that.

Comment: ok. And what I have to do if I want to read the content of the next location ? I should add 1 to the previous address or add sizeOf() to the previous address ?

Comment: Well with pointer arithmetic, adding 1 actually adds sizeof as in `int a[10]; *(a+5) = 5; //actually (a + 5 * sizeof (a))`

Comment: What on earth is "an erasure code algorithm"?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<NedeEntry*> vec;
// populate vec
char* rawData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vec);
for (char* tmp=rawData; tmp != rawData+sizeof(vec); ++tmp) {
  // extract 0s and 1s from *tmp
}
```

Note that the above code will give you the binary representation of the vector object, but depending on what you actually want, this might not be waht you are after.  For example, this code will most likely not give you the pointers you put in the vector as those are contained in a dynamically allocated array (most likely), so at best you will get the binary representation of the address of that array.

If you wanted the binary representation of the contained objects as well you will need a lot of magic as there is no portable way to figure out which byte sequece represents the address of the internal array, for example.  Or you could just iterate through the vector and perform similar logic on the individual content objects (pointers in your example).  To handle those properly, you will need custom code, etc.

Comment: The OP clearly specifies that he wants the bitstream of the *pointers*, not the vector.

Comment: @DeadMG - Where in the post does the OP say anything about wanting the pointers?  He mentioned wanting the bitstream of the object itself.  Besides, even if that was the case, I did give ideas on how to get to the pointers as well